# STI with has_one through not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My Models:

```
Content
RelatedList
RelatedGroupList < RelatedList # STI
ContentListing
```

on Content, I have

```
has_many :content_listings # all the below relations are joined using this which has content_id and related_list_id columns
has_one :related_group_list, through: :content_listings, source: 'RelatedList'
has_one :related_people_list, through: :content_listings, source: 'RelatedList'
has_one :related_website_list, through: :content_listings, source: 'RelatedList'
```

Basically, I want to get 'content.related_group_list' which should get the record for related group list.

However, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) :RelatedList in model ContentListing. Try 'has_many :related_group_list, :through => :content_listings, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :content or :related_list?
```

I checked my ContentListing model, with this line:

```
belongs_to :related_list
```

what am I missing in my ContentListing model?

---

Edit 1:

after I posted this question, I read some other articles on associations and changed the line

```
has_one :related_group_list, through: :content_listings, source: 'RelatedList'
```

to

```
has_one :related_group_list, through: :content_listings, source: :related_list
```

It now gives me the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasOneThroughCantAssociateThroughCollection: Cannot have a has_one :through association 'Content#related_group_list' where the :through association 'Content#content_listings' is a collection. Specify a has_one or belongs_to association in the :through option instead.
```

I want my

```
has_one :related_group_list, through: :content_listings, source: :related_list
```

automatically fetch me only those related_list whose type is RelatedGroupList and then join through my ContentListing. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Here you can not set has_one relationship 'related_group_list' You can set has_many.

Because Content has many content_listings and each content_listing has one related_list.
It means each content can have many related_group_list not just one.

So if you want to get content.related_group_lists then you can do

In ContentListing model -:

```
class ContentListing < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :related_list
    belongs_to :related_group_list, class_name: 'RelatedList',
    foreign_key: 'related_list_id'
    belongs_to :content
end
```

In Content model -:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :content_listings
  has_many :related_lists,  through: :content_listings
  has_many :related_group_lists, through: :content_listings
end
```

Comment: Even if I have has_many relationships, it doesn't filter out the content based on type column used for STI. is there a way to get STI based has_many?